# Internet Explorer css hack negative numbers and less compilation

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

I have a LESS file where I apply IE8 css specific hacks like:

```
#example {
   height: 46px; //ALL BROWSERS
   height: 50px\9; //ONLY IE8
}
```

When compiling from LESS to CSS the above example works, going with negative numbers raises a compilation error.

```
#example {
   height: 46px; //ALL BROWSERS
   height: -50px\9; //ONLY IE8 BUT GIVES A COMPILATION ERROR WITH LESS
}
```

I tried different solutions but none worked but modifying the css compiled file manually.

Comment: Not posting as answer because this is only a workaround, but `height: ~"-50px\9"` would solve the compilation error.

Comment: It works perfectly, so this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: What does a negative height mean?

Comment: @Ronnie: I had updated my answer based on seven-phases-max's comment but the crux of the answer remains the same. Leaving a comment just for you to make note of the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [CSS Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#escaped-characters) the backslash (`\`) character indicates a character escape. For example, a value of [`\A`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content) for the `content` property would indicate a line break. So technically, `50px\9` is valid syntax as per CSS spec.

However when the negation operator is added prior to that, parsing fails because `50px\9` is not interpreted as a number but is rather considered as an anonymous type.

Hence we would have to form the output value by using string manipulation and escaping. Putting the entire value for the property within quotes (including the `\9`) and then using the `~` or the `e()` function would make Less treat the value as a string and then output it without the quotes.

```
#example {
    height: 46px;
    height: ~"-50px\9";
}
```

or

```
#example {
    height: 46px;
    height: e("-50px\9");
}
```

**Compiled CSS:**

```
#example {
    height: 46px;
    height: -50px\9;
}
```

**References:**

- [Comment by seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020651/internet-explorer-css-hack-negative-numbers-and-less-compilation/26081273?noredirect=1#comment40867476_26081273)
- [Less GitHub Issue #2207](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2207)
- [Less GitHub Issue #1961](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1961)

Comment: To correct myself: by now I think it's not really a vendor specific hack: see [#2207](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2207). I.e. technically `\e` is just an escaped char with code 9 (if I'm not mistaken because the standard is quite blurrish about single digit codes). But in this particular case this means that `50px\9` is not interpreted as a number but rather as an "anonymous type" thus an attempt to parse it as a part of the negation expression fails. So yes, in general it's required to put `\*` stuff in qoutes.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: True, agree with the point that Less should just compile it by considering it as a string (?). But values like `\9` are very rarely used in CSS other than for such hacks and hence I don't think it is really a issue that requires a priority fix. Ofcourse values like `\00a0` are used in `content` property but they would not cause issue like this.